# How do I write optimization code in R when the initial values are not directly contained within the objective function?

Tags: r, optimization

I'm trying to write a piece of optimization code in R to calculate a set of unknown values for a biological question concerning drosophila flies.

The dataframe is composed of 13 columns (just showing 9 in code below for clarity) with varying numbers of rows.  The first three columns contain collected data and the rest of the columns are calculated using various formulas. Two of the columns, Missing_C and Missing_D are initially populated with empty data and in the optimization problem represent the initial values.

```
  Time.min. Prob_C Prob_D Miss_C Miss_D Event_C Event_D Risk_C Risk_D
1         0   1.00   1.00         0         0    0.00    0.00  86.00  78.00
2         5   0.98   0.97         0         0    1.93    1.98  84.07  76.02
3        16   0.84   0.95         0         0   10.67    1.90  73.40  74.12
4        17   0.50   0.75         0         0   21.02   12.85  52.38  61.27
5        20   0.30   0.50         0         0   14.97   15.32  37.42  45.95
```

As an example of the some of the formulas used, Event_C and Risk_C are calculated with a for loop as follows:

```
#define values for events_c and risk_c with for loops`

temp_events_c <-vector()
temp_risk_c <-vector()


for (i in 2:no_rows) {
  temp_events_c <- ((prob_c[i] * risk_c[i-1]) - (prob_c[i] * miss_c[i-1]) - (prob_c[i-1] * risk_c[i-1]) + (prob_c[i-1] * miss_c[i-1])) / (prob_c[i] - (2 * prob_c[i-1]))
  events_c[i] <- temp_events_c
  temp_risk_c <- risk_c[i-1] - miss_c[i-1] - events_c[i]
  risk_c[i] <- temp_risk_c
}
```

From this data, I also have a single, collected, value (9.1 in this instance) which relates to the values in the table.  The following function defines the relationship to this value to columns Event_C, Event_D and two columns not shown in the above, Expected_C and Expected_D where the sums of those columns are represented by x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4]:

```
fn <- function(x) ((x[1]-x[2])^2)/x[2] + ((x[3]-x[4])^2)/x[4]
```

I then would like to use a minimization algorithm i.e. `slsqp` from `nloptr` to calculate the values in the Miss_C and Miss_D which ultimately satisfy this single value. The extra code for the optimization would be something like this:

```
x0 <- c(Miss_C,Miss_D)

heq <- function(x) (((x[1]-x[2])^2)/x[2] + ((x[3]-x[4])^2)/x[4]) - 9.1  # heq == 0

slsqp(x0, fn, gr = NULL, 
      hin = NULL, heq = heq)
```

Obviously, that doesn't work as the initial values are not directly contained within the function that needs to be solved and that is the point I am stuck at!  I'm not sure if this is an optimization problem as such or more of a general R coding question - either way, any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers, Andrew

*** Edit - complete code added as per request ***

```
#input variables

time_vector <- c(0,5,16,17,20)

prob_c <- c(1,0.977,0.835,0.5,0.30)

prob_d <- c(1,0.974,0.949,0.75,0.50)

miss_c <- c(0,0,0,0,0)

miss_d <- c(0,0,0,0,0)

#get number of rows

no_rows <- length(time_vector)

#fill events columns with dummy data

events_c <- c(0:(no_rows - 1))
events_d <- c(0:(no_rows - 1))

#define starting number at risk

risk_c_t0 <- 86
risk_d_t0 <- 78


#add t0 risk to each column

risk_c <- risk_c_t0
risk_d <-risk_d_t0

#fill risk columns with dummy data

risk_c[2:no_rows] <- c(2:no_rows)
risk_d[2:no_rows] <- c(2:no_rows)


#re-define values for events_c and risk_c with for loops

temp_events_c <-vector()
temp_risk_c <-vector()


for (i in 2:no_rows) {
  temp_events_c <- ((prob_c[i] * risk_c[i-1]) - (prob_c[i] * miss_c[i-1]) - (prob_c[i-1] * risk_c[i-1]) + (prob_c[i-1] * miss_c[i-1])) / (prob_c[i] - (2 * prob_c[i-1]))
  events_c[i] <- temp_events_c
  temp_risk_c <- risk_c[i-1] - miss_c[i-1] - events_c[i]
  risk_c[i] <- temp_risk_c
}

#re-define values for events_t with for loops

temp_events_d <-vector()
temp_risk_d <-vector()

for (j in 2:no_rows) {
  temp_events_d <- ((prob_d[j] * risk_d[j-1]) - (prob_d[j] * miss_d[j-1]) - (prob_d[j-1] * risk_d[j-1]) + (prob_d[j-1] * miss_d[j-1])) / (prob_d[j] - (2 * prob_d[j-1]))
  events_d[j] <- temp_events_d
  temp_risk_d <- risk_d[j-1] - miss_d[j-1] - events_d[j]
  risk_d[j] <- temp_risk_d
}

#calculate total risk, events and expected
total_risk <- risk_c + risk_d

total_events <- events_c + events_d

expected_c <- (risk_c * (total_events/total_risk))

expected_d <- (risk_d * (total_events/total_risk))

#place values into dataframe

df1 <- data.frame(time_vector,prob_c,prob_d, miss_c, miss_d, events_c, events_d, risk_c, risk_d, total_risk, total_events, expected_c, expected_d)

#sum of values
sum_events_C <- sum(events_c)

sum_events_d <- sum(events_d)

sum_expected_c <- sum(expected_c)

sum_expected_d <- sum(expected_d)

#chi_sq formula
chi_sq_combo <- (((sum_events_C - sum_expected_c)^2)/sum_expected_c) + (((sum_events_d - sum_expected_d)^2)/sum_expected_d)


#### end of table calculations before sim

#x <- c(sum_events_C, sum_expected_c, sum_events_d, sum_expected_d)

#x0 <- c(miss_c,miss_d) #inital values


#fn <- function(x) ((x[1]-x[2])^2)/x[2] + ((x[3]-x[4])^2)/x[4]

#heq <- function(x) (((x[1]-x[2])^2)/x[2] + ((x[3]-x[4])^2)/x[4]) - 6.5  # heq == 0


#slsqp(x0, fn, gr = NULL, 
 #     hin = NULL, heq = heq)
```

Comment: You need to post a reproducible example.  It's not clear what you want:  you are passing either two values or two vectors of values  (`Miss_C` and `Miss_D`) to a function that wants a single vector of 4 values.  If you post complete code, even if it doesn't work, we'll probably be able to figure out your intention.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help.  I've added the complete code as you requested. This should work fine to make the dataframe.  The sim bit at the bottom is what I'm struggling with. Essentially, I want to create values for columns Miss_C and Miss_D such that they satisfy the chi_sq_combo value; which in this case is now 6.5. Hope that's a bit clearer now. Cheers, Andrew

Comment: Okay, the problem is that `fn` wants 4 parameters, but `x0`, which is supposed to contain your initial guesses at those parameters, contains 10 values (5 each from `miss_c` and `miss_d`).  I think from your verbal description the issue is that you are trying for something from `slsqp` that it doesn't do.  What it *does* do is find values for the vector of `x` values which minimizes `fn`, and I don't think you want that, but I'm not sure what you do want.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this again.  If we ignore the use of `slsqp` and I'll try and restate what it is I'm looking to do.  Basically,  the `chi_sq_combo` value links back to various pieces of the data in the dataframe. What I am trying to calculate is values in `Miss_C` and `Miss_D` which when they go through the rest of the different formula satisfy `chi_sq_combo` such that it equals 6.5 (in this instance).  Essentially, it's just simulating values for `Miss_C` and `Miss_D`, running the rest of the formula and checking `chi_sq_combo` equals 6.5; if no, re-run with different values and so on.

Comment: I consider it a minimization problem as I'm able to do the same sort of thing in Excel, using Excel's solver plugin.  I am trying to re-write this in R so I can automate it more easily in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Rephrasing the comments above, I believe the problem is to use optimization to find
two values which yield a target chi-square value.  A complication which may cause problems is that there are likely many solutions that yield the target, so it might be necessary to add some other requirement to make the answer unique.

To do this, you need a function of two variables which calculates the square of the difference between the chi-square value using those variables and the target value, and then you minimize that.

For example,

```
fn2 <- function(x) {
  c <- x[1]
  d <- x[2]
  chisq <- (((c - sum_expected_c)^2)/sum_expected_c) + 
           (((d - sum_expected_d)^2)/sum_expected_d)
  (chisq - 6.5)^2
}
for (i in 1:no_rows) {
  x0 <- c(df1$miss_c[i],df1$miss_d[i]) #initial values
  res <- nloptr::slsqp(x0, fn2)
  miss_c[i] <- res$par[1]
  miss_d[i] <- res$par[2]
}
```

This gives the same values all 5 times, so I might not have understood you completely.

Comment: Hi, thanks again for your input.  Yes, that is a possible complication; the actual dataset I will be using would have many more data points than in the example above so should have a unique solution.  Even if it didn't, you could run Monte Carlo simulations to come to an average.  In terms of the problem, I think I need to pass 5 * 2 = 10 variables to the function; one for every unknown number in the two columns and then use this to solve for chi_sq_combo. I therefore think I need to embed the rest of the script in the function to do this. Sorry if it's still not clear.  Cheers, Andrew